# formatting when writing to an xml file

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

```
  $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
  $doc->load('xml/lead.xml');
  $doc->formatOutput = true; 


  $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('RootElement');
  $r = $tags->item(0);

   $a = $doc->createElement( 'Lead' );
   $r->appendChild( $a );

   $b = $doc->createElement( 'Contact' ); 
  $b->setAttribute('FirstName', ''.$name.'');
  $b->setAttribute('LastName', ''.$last_name.'');
  $b->setAttribute('Email', ''.$email.'');
  $b->setAttribute('StreetAddress', ''.$address.'');
  $b->setAttribute('City', ''.$city.'');

  $a->appendChild( $b ); 

  $c = $doc->createElement( 'Qualifications' );

  $a->appendChild( $c );

  $d = $doc->createElement( 'PropertyInterest' );
  $d->setAttribute("BuilderName","Test");

  $a->appendChild( $d );
```

outputs to a file and looks like

```
<RootElement>






<Lead><Contact FirstName="test " LastName="test" Email="testk@gmail.com" StreetAddress="n/a" City="test"/><Qualifications/><PropertyInterest BuilderName="test"/></Lead></RootElement>
```

there's tons of whitespace... im submitting this to a CRM and i'm assuming that whitespace does make a difference in how it's parsed.

So, how do I format the xml using the DOMDocument?

Comment: How are you dumping/printing the generated output?

Comment: actually if it's a proper XML parser it will ignore whitespace. You could also try writing the XML file from scratch, it seems to me the file you're loading has the whitespace in it.

Comment: You could try outputting it to a string, and then parse it with Tidy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [format xml string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616540/format-xml-string/3616722#3616722)

Comment: also see [`DOMDocument::preserveWhiteSpace`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace)

Comment: The comments above are all correct, but after looking at your code I'm confused.  You're reading an XML document then outputting to the same file?

Answer (score 0):

if that lib is anything like jdom you should be able to set the format on the outputter. something along theses lines:

```
out.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
```