# Formatting XML for output file

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I've got my code working to output an XML file based on an HTML form, but the output format is just a long string like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<students>
<student><name>Joey Lowery</name><email>jlowery@idest.com</email><cell>555-555-5555</cell><dob>1999-03-31</dob><study>8</study></student></students>
```

rather than this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<students>
  <student>
    <name>Joey Lowery</name>
    <email>jlowery@idest.com</email>
    <cell>555-555-5555</cell>
    <dob>1999-03-31</dob>
   <study>8</study>
  </student>
</students>
```

I am using `formatOutput = true` as well as `preserveWhiteSpace = false`, but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file = "data.xml";
$userNode = 'student';

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->load($file);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;   
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$root = $doc->documentElement; 

$post = $_POST;
unset($post['submit']);

$user = $doc->createElement($userNode);
$user = $root->appendChild($user);

foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
    $node = $doc->createElement($key, $value);
    $user->appendChild($node);
}
$doc->save($file) or die("Error");
header('Location: thanks.php'); 
}
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616540/format-xml-string/3616722#3616722.

Comment: I'm trying to save it to a file and that answer doesn't seem to apply. Thanks for trying, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `saveXML()` method instead.

Update:

```
file_put_contents($file, $doc->saveXML());
```

Update 2:

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php), specifically the comment from devin. He states you should put `preserveWhitespace` BEFORE the `load` (as the link Rolando Isidoro gave also states).

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->load('data.xml');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
file_put_contents('test.xml', $doc->saveXML());
```

Comment: Could you be more explicit? I tried adding `$doc = saveXML();` prior to saving it as a file, but no go.

Comment: I've also tried $test1 = $doc->saveXML(); - but again, no love. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: saveXML outputs a string, you need to store and save that, for example with `file_put_contents()`

Comment: Still no love. It's saving the data, but not formatted. Any other ideas?

Comment: I ran it on my server, and outputs the XML formatted. No idea what's wrong.

Comment: Did you read Update 2?

Comment: And I did try moving the preserveWhitespace as well. What version of PHP are you running, Pritaeas?

Comment: Ah - I think I found the problem - Devin's comment further says "CAUTION: If your loaded xml file (test.xml) has an empty root node that is not shortened or has no children this will NOT work." And he's right. So, adding a comment does the trick. Whew! Thanks for hanging in there! Answer accepted and upvoted!