# Is it possible to format source code after preg_replace/str_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am removing several code lines from an xml file with preg_replace and str_replace

```
preg_replace('/(<!DOCTYPE(.*?)<fields )/s', '<fields ', $readSettings);
```

after the replace is done I am left with an empty spaces where the lines were. 
http://prntscr.com/3hegmb  line 4 and 5 
Is there any way to reformat the file once I am done or to remove the line and its space completely?

Comment: See [`Tidy`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)

Comment: @AlexHowansky, thnx but it requires additional lib install and specific setup , the code I am using is intended for a lot of people and there is no way that their environment would match.

Comment: Wrap your code with `if (class_exists('Tidy')) { ... }`

Comment: Found a solution here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616540/format-xml-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are asking. Can you post an example of the HTML you get after the RegEx?

This will remove excess white space.

```
preg_replace( '~\s{2,}~', '', $str );
```

You could also look at PHP DOM (PHP Manual). Load the HTML into that and then set preserveWhiteSpace and formatOutput to false.

**Addition**:

```
preg_replace( '~\s+\n+\s+\n+~', "\n", $str );
```

Will do it I think. But as mentioned you can do this with PHP DOM, and it will be more flexible.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $html );
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true; // Or false?
$doc->formatOutput = true;
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I posted the link already, here again http://prntscr.com/3hegmb, your suggestion is removing all spaces from xml file. I want to clean the formating up