# How to keep indentation when using blocks in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, indentation

I try to make a pretty RSS Feed in a Symfony project. For each item, I include one file. It's ok but when I look the output, Twig **reset indentation in the block element**. Here an example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
  xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
  xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
  xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
>
  <channel>
    <title>Space Raclette</title>
    <description></description>
    <language>fr</language>
    <lastBuildDate>Wed, 30 Nov 2016 11:22:45 +0100</lastBuildDate>

<item>
  <title>Topic de l&#039;Ć©tĆ© du Capitaine Crochet 2</title>
  <link>...</link>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">.../39fa</guid>
  <description></description>
</item>


<item>
  <title>Topic de l&#039;Ć©tĆ© du Capitaine Crochet</title>
  <link>...</link>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">.../39fa</guid>
  <description></description>
</item>

  </channel>
</rss>
```

What can I do to keep the indentation without have bad indentation in the "item file" ? I tried to play with `spaceless` and `-`, without success.

Here my files if it can help.

**layout.rss.twig :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
  xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
  xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
  xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
>

  <channel>
    <title>{{ channel.brand }}</title>
    <atom:link href="{{ app.request.uri }}" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>{{ url }}</link>
    <description>{{ channel.description|striptags }}</description>
    <language>{{ channel.lang }}</language>
    <lastBuildDate>{{ last_publication.published|date('D, d M Y H:i:s O') }}</lastBuildDate>

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

  </channel>
</rss>
```

**index.rss.twig**

```
{% extends 'RSSBundle::layout.rss.twig' %}
{% block content %}
  {% for publication in web_publications %}
    {{ include('RSSBundle:Publication:_single.rss.twig') }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**_single.rss.twig**

```
<item>
  <title>{{ publication.title }}</title>
  <link>{{ url }}</link>
  <description></description>
  <pubDate>{{ publication.published|date('D, d M Y H:i:s O') }}</pubDate>
</item>
```

Comment: Is it just white space you need `visually` or do you want spaces (indentation) in the source code (view source in browser)?

Comment: @AlvinBunk as we are in an XML feed, it's the same in this case. But it's for the source code, yep.

Comment: This will be a pain. You'd better create a function that will take your rss as input and will return your beautified rss as output. For example: `{{ beautify_xml(include("hello.rss.twig")) }}` where `beautify_xml` will be in a twig extension with [this implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3616722/731138).

Comment: Thx @AlainTiemblo for your comment. Seems to be "overkill" just for good indentation... I don't want to lose in performance for that, so I'll keep what I currently have.

Comment: There are low-level extensions to do that, like "tidy html" and there are probably others. I developed some code generators and believe me, I prefer running the cs-fixer post generation than taking care of cs when writting my templates.

Answer (score 1):

Twig [can remove whitespace](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#templates-whitespace-control) characters in some cases, but it never adds them. So most obvious and simple solution is just to indent the included template.

> Whitespace is not further modified by the template engine, so each whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines etc.) is returned unchanged.

You can post-process the result XML. For example you can load it into the `DOMDocument` and dump with [`formatOutput`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.formatoutput) option. Or through the [`tidy`](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php). Anyway it requires a some additional work.

But (IMHO), Twig is not a right tool for XML processing. Better use any standard API to build XML, such as `DOMDocument` (with [`formatOutput`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.formatoutput)) or `XMLWriter` (with [`setIndent()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.xmlwriter-set-indent.php)).